# Replace operation on a dataframe MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, multi-index

I have two dataframes where I am trying to replace substring on level1 of multi index with another substring but this fails

For example I have a dataframe df

```
Index0   Index1    0     1     2
A        BX       .2    .3    .9      
         CX       .34   .55   .54           

D        EX       .34   .44   .32
         FX       .43.  .88.  .06
```

I am trying to **replace** the **Index1** substring **X** by **Y** so that my result
looks like as follows

```
Index0   Index1    0     1     2
A        BY       .2    .3    .9      
         CY       .34   .55   .54           

D        EY       .34   .44   .32
         FY       .43.  .88.  .06
```

I am using the following function

```
df.replace('X','Y')
```

however i get the following error

```
AttributeError                   Traceback (most recent   call last)
<ipython-input-56-fc7014a2d950> in <module>()
  8 
  9 
---> 10 df.replace('X','Y')

AttributeError: 'MultiIndex' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Comment: please add your code for creating df. Really, `df` looks like an Index

Comment: df is a dataframe. and Index0 and Index1 are the Index of df dataframe.

Comment: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-fc7014a2d950> in <module>()
      8 
      9 
---> 10 df.replace('X','Y')

AttributeError: 'MultiIndex' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Yes, and I want to modify the Multiindex substring with another substring as highlighted above but I am unable to do it and hence my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ improved on my answer so I will leave just a slower alternate here...

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,3), 
                  index=[list('aabb'), [n + 'X' for n in list('abcd')]])
```

Here's an alternate method using `reset_index`.  This would be applicable if you wanted to replace in more than one column.  The trick is that you can't use `replace` on the Index so you have to "bring it into" the DataFrame.

```
new = (df.reset_index()
           .select_dtypes(include=['object'])
           .apply(lambda col: col.str.replace('X', 'Y')))

df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new.values.tolist())
```

Comment: Good approach - I was playing with one that used `reset_index` - pushing the index into editable dataframe columns - then using `set_index` to push those values back into the index. This is less invasive; more elegant.

Comment: I don't think using a series just to do a simple replacement is the best way to do this.

Comment: @Coldspeed no but isn't that catchy??

Answer (score 3):

Or Try this

```
df.index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(x[0], x[1].replace('X', 'Y')) for x in df.index])
df
Out[304]: 
             0         1         2
a aY -0.696181 -1.929523 -1.903956
  bY  0.071061 -0.594185 -2.005251
b cY -0.097761  0.093667  1.780550
  dY  0.127887  1.534395  0.352351
```

Comment: There is a loop here. But still, better.

Comment: The only solution I could understand ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You're doing more than you need to.

```
df 
                  0     1     2
Index0 Index1                  
A      BX        .2    .3  0.90
       CX       .34   .55  0.54
D      EX       .34   .44  0.32
       FX      .43.  .88.  0.06
```

Use `pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays` and you can do this in one step.

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.index.get_level_values(0),
                                       df.index.levels[1].str.replace('X', 'Y')])

df
                  0     1     2
Index0 Index1                  
A      BY        .2    .3  0.90
       CY       .34   .55  0.54
D      EY       .34   .44  0.32
       FY      .43.  .88.  0.06
```

---

**Performance**

```
%%timeit
new = (df.reset_index()
            .select_dtypes(include=['object'])
            .apply(lambda col: col.str.replace('X', 'Y')))

df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new.values.tolist())

10 loops, best of 3: 93.5 ms per loop
```

Nearly `100ms` for a tiny dataframe. Contrast with:

```
%%timeit
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.index.get_level_values(0),
                                        df.index.levels[1].str.replace('X', 'Y')])

1000 loops, best of 3: 934 µs per loop
```

Comment: You are right, thought `str.replace` could not operate on Index.  This should be the accepted answer then @user2560244